# Android: View transition animation with view.setY() wouldn't work

Tags: android, animation, android-appbarlayout

I'm trying to animate a view by changing it's y position (startY to endY) using valueAnimator. This is my code

```
    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(startY, endY);
    valueAnimator.setDuration(150);
    valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {

            float newY = (Float) animation.getAnimatedValue();

            view.setY(newY);

            // Do some other related ui changes for each y (Important)

        }

    });

    valueAnimator.start();
```

This code works on some newer android versions. But, it doesn't work with many other android versions. So, the view's y position never gets updated. The view will continue to stay the same.

I know, I can use TransitionAnimation class and it works well (Already tried). But, TransitionAnimation class doesn't provide a listener for every new y value like onAnimationUpdate() in ValueAnimator class. So, I cannot do the other related ui changes when the y is being updated. So, I have to stick with ValueAnimator class.

More info: The views that I'm trying to animate are an AppBarLayout and a fragment below the AppBarLayout. The reason that I'm not using                 appBarLayout.setExpanded() is because the animation is too slow and Google hasn't release the new update to control setExpanded() speed yet.

Any suggestions/work arounds will be greatly appreciated. Thanks